# save value from Custom TextArea in Jqgrid to server using ajax

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with dynamic columns and model. In that grid I have textarea formatter in one column .I want to save values from all rows textarea in database on button click. I am able to do that successfully in IE but in Chrome and Firefox, `jQuery("#tblAppendGrid").getRowData()` is not providing values inputted in textarea.

Comment: to get an answer, it is much better to show (a minimal version) of your code, instead of describing your code in text.

Comment: Sorry, but your description of your code allows many interpretations.Do you use custom formatter which creates textarea in some columns on the grid? Do you defined unformatter together with formatter? Or do you start inline/cell editing of one/all row of the grid and you use `edittype: "textarea"`? How you fill the grid with data? Which `datatype` have the grid? Do you use `loadonce: true`? Do you use paging of data? **Which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and in which version you use?**

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your suggestions,Actually I am using custom formatter which creates text area in one of my column on the grid.

Comment: I have achived it solution by adding an hidden field also with my text area and on changeevent of my textarea saving value to that hidden field like :-function CommentsBox(cellvalue, options, rowObject)
         {
            var resend = "<textarea id='TextArea" + index + "'  rows='2' cols='10' onchange=\" var value=$('#TextArea" + index + "').val();$('#Hidden" + index + "').val(value); \"  >" + cellvalue + "</textarea><input id='Hidden" + index + "' type='hidden' />";             
             index++;  return resend;        
         }

Comment: Now I am facing another issue ,I need to pass my grid data to my web service which i doing using jQuery("#tblAppendGrid").getRowData();JSON.stringify(gridData); but is showing me an error of "Invalid object passed in" due to html tages of textarea and hidden field in json string.

Comment: var gridData = jQuery("#tblAppendGrid").getRowData();
             alert(gridData);
             var postData = JSON.stringify(gridData);
             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "LoadDashBoardData.asmx/SaveRCPreparationNotes",                 
                data: '{ "testData":"' + postData + '"}',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (data) { alert("Saved!"); },
                 failure: function (errMsg) {
                 }
             });